# TimeoutException: android.content.res.AssetManager.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android

I encountered this issue many times in `Crashlytics`. I am not sure what is the real issue behind this bug. Do anyone has a suggestion?

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.content.res.AssetManager.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```